# How to list all managed files?

Tags: media, files

I need to get Drupal to list all its files and their management status for debugging purposes. It seems like there must be a simple way to print the list of managed files, right? How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least 1 issue queue item looking to add "reporting" to the Media module, such as show me where this file is used on the site.

If you're using Drush. Look at `drush sql-cli` and a query such as `select fid, filename from file_managed where status = 1`

Comment: This is correct. It turns out I asked the wrong question, because I wanted to look at the file *usage* table instead, but this is still helpful because I didn't know about drush sql-cli before this.

Comment: see this issue regarding tracking asset usage on a site. http://drupal.org/node/1599460

Comment: So, this is great, but is there really no API call that returns a list of files?

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_usage_list/7

Comment: There we go, that's what I was looking for. Thank you!